# Modelo como String Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Estimados estoy tratando de hacer una consulta mediante un modelo con un String.

Me llegan unos datos los cuales coloco en el array $criterioBusqueda y después hago un if y un foreach para filtrar por si el array viene vacío y el foreach es para meter esos datos un ->where() de laravel para poder enganchar varios filtros a la vez y por ultimo tengo una consulta con el modelo entrecomillado para hacerlo string y poder enganchar dichas condiciones el problem es que no se como hacer que se ejecute y muestre resultados, es para hacer un buscador con varios filtros aplicados directamente.

código:

```
$criterioBusqueda=[];
if ($request->cliente!=null) {$criterioBusqueda['cliente']= $request->cliente;}
if ($request->sede!=null) {$criterioBusqueda['sede'] = $request->sede;}
if ($request->tipo!=null) {$criterioBusqueda['tipo']= $request->tipo;}
if ($request->of!=null) {$criterioBusqueda['Oferta']= $request->of;}
 $query='';
if (count($criterioBusqueda)>0) {
    foreach ($criterioBusqueda as $key => $value) {$query.="->where($key,$value)";}


$queryPrincipal="venta::where([['estado','aceptado'],['sedeSelect_id',null],['estado_envio','enviado']])".$query;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Cuando crees filtros de la base de datos hay una mejor opción que utilizar únicamente `where`, puedes utilizar [`when()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#conditional-clauses) que evalua si el filtro existe o no, si está vacío lo ignora, de lo contrario aplica el filtro a la base de datos

```
$query = Venta::query()
    ->when($request->cliente, fn($query, $cliente) => $query->where('cliente', 'like', '%'.$cliente.'%'))
    ->when($request->sede, fn($query, $sede) => $query->where('sede', 'like', '%'.$sede.'%'))
    ->when($request->tipo, fn($query, $tipo) => $query->where('tipo', 'like', '%'.$tipo.'%'))
    ->when($request->of, fn($query, $of) => $query->where('Oferta', 'like', '%'.$of.'%'))
    ->get();
```

Explicación, `when` evalua si la variable está vacía o no, en caso de no estarlo entonces aplica el `where`.

De esa forma se crean los filtros "dinámicos" por ejemplo al crear la búsqueda avanzada en una página donde existen multiples `input` y se deve evaluar si el usuario ha escrito algo para filtrar los datos o no.

Comment: Nunca me acuerdo que existe `when()`, buena respuesta.

Comment: yo ni sabia que existía, when() facilita mucho la vida, Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No hay de que, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

No tenés que tratar nada como un string. Es cuestión de ir anidando los distintos `where()`.

Supongo que tu Modelo se llama Venta (con V mayúscula, o debería):

```
// Primero definís el query inicial
$queryPrincipal = Venta::where([['estado', 'aceptado'], ['sedeSelect_id', null], ['estado_envio', 'enviado']]);

// Luego vas agregando cada where por separado
if ($request->cliente != null) {
    $queryPrincipal->where('cliente', $request->cliente);
}

if ($request->sede != null) {
    $queryPrincipal->where('sede', $request->sede);
}

if ($request->tipo != null) {
    $queryPrincipal->where('tipo', $request->tipo);
}

if ($request->of != null) {
    $queryPrincipal->where('Oferta', $request->of);
}

// Por último ejecutás la consulta
$queryPrincipal->get();
```

No se como querés mostrar los datos, pero `get()` ejecuta la consulta.

Desconozco si está bien tu primera definición del `where()` con arrays, nunca usé esa sintaxis, pero leyendo rápido la documentación puede que esté bien.

Answer (score 0):

Mira, en Laravel puedes hacerlo así como te pongo abajo

```
<?php
$criterioBusqueda = [];
if ($request->cliente != null) {
    $criterioBusqueda['cliente'] = $request->cliente;
}
if ($request->sede != null) {
    $criterioBusqueda['sede'] = $request->sede;
}
if ($request->tipo != null) {
    $criterioBusqueda['tipo'] = $request->tipo;
}
if ($request->of != null) {
    $criterioBusqueda['Oferta'] = $request->of;
}
$query = Venta::where([['estado', 'aceptado'], ['sedeSelect_id', null], ['estado_envio', 'enviado']]);

if (count($criterioBusqueda) > 0) {
    foreach ($criterioBusqueda as $key => $value) {
        $query->where($key, $value);//añadido de datos al filtro
    }
}
$resultado = $query->get();//ejecucion
```

Cambié la variable $query que tenías como un string y un [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) porque te va a ser más cómodo ya que lo vas a manipular como objeto.

Ésta línea que ves aquí, dentro del loop es la que añadirá uno a uno los filtros. La ventaja de éste objeto es que los filtros se van almacenando en el mismo objeto, por ende puedes utilizar el loop que ya usas.

```
$query->where($key, $value);//añadido de datos al filtro
```

Finalmente, ésta línea es la que te devuelve un [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections) para que puedas utilizarlo con todas sus funcionalidades.

```
$resultado = $query->get();//ejecucion
```

Si tu código va a regresar mucha información y necesitas procesarla, te recomiendo el uso de un `foreach` junto con la función cursor() sobre la variable `$query`. Eso hará que ahorres memoría y el tiempo de respuesta va a mejorar considerablemente.

En [ésta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53736557/2658796) hay una tabla informativa sobre lo que te comento.
Si quieres usar `cursor()` podrías utilizarlo así:

Ej:

```
foreach($query->cursor() as $venta){
...
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es lo más parecida a lo que ya tiene armado. Pero la realidad es que no tiene sentido ir agregando los _where_ en un array para después recorrerlo. Para eso definí antes la primera parte de la consulta y en cada _if_ directamente agregá el _where_ correspondiente.

Comment: @azeós La cosa es que eso que comentas es muy buena idea pero es una sugerencia que no tiene que ver con lo que preguntaron.

Comment: Buen día @Wisquimas, hay veces que las preguntas no aplican la mejor estrategia para lograr lo que se espera. En este caso la meta final es poder utilizar muchas variables para filtrar, es por eso que se han propuesto otras estrategias que permitan llegar al objetivo de una mejor forma. Al mismo tiempo estoy de acuerdo en que se provea una solución utilizando el mismo método de la pregunta. Saludos